# How to toggle action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

=== QUESTION NR.1 ===

*Does anyone know how to make this javascript toogle-bar? I know about toogleClass but how can use it in this case?*

```
$('.gallery').click(function(e){
            var itemNumber = ('#myCarousel2 .item').length;

            console.log('broj slika je' + ' ' + itemNumber);
            if (itemNumber >= 4){
                $('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item').addClass('active');
                console.log('added Active class!');
                $('#myCarousel2').addClass('thumbnail-gallery');
                $('.modal').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            };
        });
```

*I am trying to revert the action on the **second** .gallery click. Once the user has clicked on .gallery element it is added this .active class which i will to remove on the second click of the class **.gallery** .*

**update::**

I am talking here about Twitter bootstrap. If I do that it will remove all my active (including this one of the current image) classes which are additionally added to item. I want to remove only the class active which I recently added.

**Update nr.2 - Solution for the first problem**

Here is solution for [toogleing](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) the click function:

```
var itemNumber = ('#myCarousel2 .item').length;
        $(".gallery").toggle(
        function() {
            if (itemNumber >= 4){
                $('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item:not(.active)').addClass("active");
                console.log('added Active class!');
                $('#myCarousel2').addClass('thumbnail-gallery');
                $('.modal').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            };
        }, 
        function() {
            $('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item').removeClass('active');
            console.log('added Active class!');
            $('#myCarousel2').removeClass('thumbnail-gallery');
            $('.modal').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        });
```

=== QUESTION NR.2 ===

Still I am searching for an answer for my second problem which appears when I try to remove all classes which I have added additionally. Does anyone has solution for this??

Comment: could you post a link to your full code or site please?

Comment: You call it `itemNumber` but you're getting a count of all items--is that desired? Because jQuery has `.index()` to get the order of that item.

Comment: yeah itemNumber is used to get the number of .item elements.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check that active class present or not.

```
 if($('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item')hasClass('active')){
    $('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item')removeClass('active');
 }
```

Comment: I am talking here about Twitter bootstrap. If I do that it will remove all my active (including this one of the current image) classes which are additionally added to item. I want to remove only the class active which I recently added.

Comment: @CoderXx: I think you'd better update your question with that information.  Sounds like an important caveat.

Answer (score 0):

To toogle the class you have to do something like this :

```
$('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item').toggleClass("active");
```

To select all the item that are not active you need something like this :

```
$('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item:not(.active)').addClass("active");
```

Comment: Ok, this solves one problem but my first solution gave same result. Now I am wondering how to remove all this additional classes?